# How do I get my DualShock 2 controller to work as an XBOX 360 controller for Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, controllers

Recently I bought a PS2 to PC adapter (the blue one that allows two controllers to be plugged into) and it works fine.

I tried a program called xPadder and it works, but it doesn't have an XBOX 360 emulator. So I tried another problem called MotionInJoy, the problem with this program is that it does not recognize my controller.. I'm hoping I don't have to purchase another adapter, everyone's saying you need a bluetooth adapter.

Is there another program I can use to emulate an XBOX 360 controller?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [x360ce](http://code.google.com/p/x360ce/) to emulate an Xbox 360 controller with any old DirectInput controller.

Comment: I tried this earlier today, was watching a tutorial on it. You have to drag some files into the games' folder right? I did so, but when I logged onto Skyrim, my controller didn't respond to the keys I pressed/moved, and the cursor was still on the screen.

Comment: That's because you have to run x360ce to configure it first.

Comment: Is there a way to instant message with you? I have a few things to ask you. Do you have a steam account I befriend?

Comment: I do, same name as on here.

Comment: Ok, we shall talk this over on Steam.

Comment: kotekzot, I give up too man..

Comment: kotekzot, I fixed my problem. I just need to restore the folder I was using yesterday when you helped me. I had deleted it from the bin, thanks so much man!

Comment: Glad to hear! What did you have to do?

Comment: I had the XBOX 360 controller setting off the whole time.. I think it was from the first time I tried turning it off to use my DualShock 2 controller.

Answer (score 1):

A few months back, I used a PS3 controller to play various games on the PC. One of these such games was Skyrim.

I first opened MotionInJoy, and configured it for the PS3 controller. This allowed my computer to recognize the controller.

I would then run xPadder, and created a controller set up for Skyrim.

When launching the game, I ran into several smaller bugs, but it was highly playable. One of such bugs was being unable to change some controls, including third-person.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to tell me, but I first tried playing Skyrim using xpadder, too. I don't anymore because I don't like the fact that you have to use a cursor instead of just using your controller to select stuff.

Comment: I used both at the same time. Motion In Joy allowed my controller to succesfully connect to the PC, and xPadder allows you to switch up controls for each game. I'm not sure I ran into the inventory issue, but I may have had a mod installed that changed the inventory system for me.

Comment: Do you know how to connect a DualShock 2 controller to MotionInJoy without having to buy a bluetooth? I already have an adapter.

Comment: You don't need MotionJoy if your computer already recognizes your controller, as is the case for you.

Comment: Are you talking to me, or Domocus? lol

Comment: @zCynic I was talking to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [XInput Wrapper for DS3 (Dual Shock 3)](http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-XInput-Wrapper-for-DS3-and-Play-com-USB-Dual-DS2-) as its much cleaner and I found it easier to setup that Motion in Joy.